# dplyr::mutate to add multiple values

Tags: r, dplyr

There are a couple of issues about this on the [dplyr Github repo](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr) already, and at least one related SO question, but none of them quite covers my question -- I think.

- [Adding multiple columns in a dplyr mutate call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936330/adding-multiple-columns-in-a-dplyr-mutate-call) is more or less what I want, but there's a special-case answer for that case (`tidyr::separate`) that doesn't (I think) work for me.
- [This issue](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/372) ("summarise or mutate with functions returning multiple values/columns") says "use `do()`".

Here's my use case: I want to compute exact binomial confidence intervals

```
dd <- data.frame(x=c(3,4),n=c(10,11))
get_binCI <- function(x,n) {
    rbind(setNames(c(binom.test(x,n)$conf.int),c("lwr","upr")))
}
with(dd[1,],get_binCI(x,n))
##             lwr       upr
## [1,] 0.06673951 0.6524529
```

I can get this done with `do()` but I wonder if there's a more expressive way to do this (it feels like `mutate()` *could* have a `.n` argument [as is being discussed for summarise()](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/154) ...)

```
library("dplyr")
dd %>% group_by(x,n) %>%
    do(cbind(.,get_binCI(.$x,.$n)))

## Source: local data frame [2 x 4]
## Groups: x, n
## 
##   x  n        lwr       upr
## 1 3 10 0.06673951 0.6524529
## 2 4 11 0.10926344 0.6920953
```

Comment: Are you settled to do this particularly with `dplyr`? With, `data.table` you can quickly do `setDT(dd)[, as.list(get_binCI(x, n)), by = .(x, n)]` Though my mind reading skills are not allowing me to determine what do you exactly mean by "*expressive way*"...

Comment: This is certainly good.  I *was* hoping for a `dplyr` answer (although I will not be surprised if my solution above is the best one can do ATM).  I have nothing against `data.table`, but I prefer `dplyr`, and -- mostly -- I'm still spending a lot of brainpower getting my head around it, don't really want to add a whole new set of syntax (nor inflict it on my students and colleagues) at the moment.  But if you answer that way I'll upvote, it's useful.

Comment: Hi all, hoping to bump this up; is there now a better way to do this with nesting? I'm trying but haven't gotten it yet.

Comment: @Aaron, I've had a go at using `unnest` that also uses `map2` that you might be interested in

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yet another variant, although I think we're all splitting hairs here.

```
> dd <- data.frame(x=c(3,4),n=c(10,11))
> get_binCI <- function(x,n) {
+   as_data_frame(setNames(as.list(binom.test(x,n)$conf.int),c("lwr","upr")))
+ }
> 
> dd %>% 
+   group_by(x,n) %>%
+   do(get_binCI(.$x,.$n))
Source: local data frame [2 x 4]
Groups: x, n

  x  n        lwr       upr
1 3 10 0.06673951 0.6524529
2 4 11 0.10926344 0.6920953
```

Personally, if we're just going by readability, I find this preferable:

```
foo  <- function(x,n){
    bi <- binom.test(x,n)$conf.int
    data_frame(lwr = bi[1],
               upr = bi[2])
}

dd %>% 
    group_by(x,n) %>%
    do(foo(.$x,.$n))
```

...but now we're *really* splitting hairs.

Comment: tuns out I didn't need the `data.frame()` anyway (see edits).

Comment: ... and ... in my real use case I need to group on something other than `x` and `n` ... but I might be able to use this

Comment: I think your second solution wins, but I'll hold off on accepting for a little while.

Comment: @weymouth Try the [magrittr vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html).

Answer (score 18):

Yet another option could be to use the `purrr::map` family of functions.

If you replace `rbind` with `dplyr::bind_rows` in the `get_binCI` function:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dd <- data.frame(x = c(3, 4), n = c(10, 11))
get_binCI <- function(x, n) {
  bind_rows(setNames(c(binom.test(x, n)$conf.int), c("lwr", "upr")))
}
```

You can use `purrr::map2` with `tidyr::unnest`:

```r
dd %>% mutate(result = map2(x, n, get_binCI)) %>% unnest()

#>   x  n        lwr       upr
#> 1 3 10 0.06673951 0.6524529
#> 2 4 11 0.10926344 0.6920953
```

Or `purrr::map2_dfr` with `dplyr::bind_cols`:

```r
dd %>% bind_cols(map2_dfr(.$x, .$n, get_binCI))

#>   x  n        lwr       upr
#> 1 3 10 0.06673951 0.6524529
#> 2 4 11 0.10926344 0.6920953
```

Comment: In dplyr 0.8.5 this will need to be `dd %>% mutate(result = map2(x, n, get_binCI)) %>% unnest(result)`.  Also, the help for unnest suggests it is mainly intended for lists of data frames.  Alternative approaches are suggested in the help file.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a quick solution using `data.table` package instead

First, a little change to the function

```
get_binCI <- function(x,n) as.list(setNames(binom.test(x,n)$conf.int, c("lwr", "upr")))
```

Then, simply

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dd)[, get_binCI(x, n), by = .(x, n)]
#    x  n        lwr       upr
# 1: 3 10 0.06673951 0.6524529
# 2: 4 11 0.10926344 0.6920953
```

Comment: here is a base solution @David Arenburg!! `dd[, c('lwr','upr')] <- t(mapply(get_binCI, dd[, 1], dd[, 2]))`

Comment: @rawr I'm not sure why you are posting this as a comment under my answer :) I would suggest you post this as your own solution (I promise to upvote).

Comment: @rawr, is `Map()` safer (no simplification)?

Comment: @BenBolker but I guess you'd also have to use a `do.call`, though, right?

Comment: I thought `Map()` and `mapply()` were basically identical: `‘Map’ is a simple wrapper to ‘mapply’ which does not attempt to simplify the result, similar to Common Lisp's ‘mapcar’ (with arguments being recycled, however). `

Comment: @BenBolker the only difference is that mapply's default is `SIMPLIFY  = TRUE` and map is false, and also you cannot change map's default obviously

Answer (score 7):

Here are some possibilities with `rowwise` and `nesting`.

```
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")
```

data frame with repeated x/n combinations, for fun

```
dd <- data.frame(x=c(3, 4, 3), n=c(10, 11, 10))
```

a versions of the CI function that returns a data frame, like @Joran's

```
get_binCI_df <- function(x,n) {
  binom.test(x, n)$conf.int %>% 
    setNames(c("lwr", "upr")) %>% 
    as.list() %>% as.data.frame()
}
```

Grouping by `x` and `n` as before, removes the duplicate.

```
dd %>% group_by(x,n) %>% do(get_binCI_df(.$x,.$n))
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
# # Groups:   x, n [2]
#       x     n       lwr       upr
#   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1     3    10 0.1181172 0.8818828
# 2     4    11 0.1092634 0.6920953
```

Using `rowwise` keeps all the rows but removes `x` and `n` unless you put them back using `cbind(.` (like Ben does in his OP).

```
dd %>% rowwise() %>% do(cbind(., get_binCI_df(.$x,.$n)))
# Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
# Groups: <by row>
#   
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#       x     n        lwr       upr
# * <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1     3    10 0.06673951 0.6524529
# 2     4    11 0.10926344 0.6920953
# 3     3    10 0.06673951 0.6524529
```

It feels like nesting could work more cleanly, but this is as good as I can get. Using `mutate` means I can use `x` and `n` directly instead of `.$x` and `.$n`, but mutate expects a single value, so it needs to be wrapped in `list`.

```
dd %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(ci=list(get_binCI_df(x, n))) %>% unnest()
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#       x     n        lwr       upr
#   <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1     3    10 0.06673951 0.6524529
# 2     4    11 0.10926344 0.6920953
# 3     3    10 0.06673951 0.6524529
```

Finally, looks like something like this is an open issue (as of 5 Oct 2017) for dplyr; see https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2326; if something like that is implemented then that will be the easiest way!

Answer (score 5):

This uses a "standard" dplyr workflow, but as @BenBolker notes in the comments, it requires calling `get_binCI` twice:

```
dd %>% group_by(x,n) %>%
  mutate(lwr=get_binCI(x,n)[1],
         upr=get_binCI(x,n)[2])

  x  n        lwr       upr
1 3 10 0.06673951 0.6524529
2 4 11 0.10926344 0.6920953
```

Comment: Yes, it's a solution, but the ugliness of this is having to call `get_binCI()` twice. Sort of in the eye of the beholder as to whether this is better or worse than `do(cbind(.,data.frame(get_binCI(.$x,.$n)))` (I could get rid of the `data.frame()` by sticking it inside `get_binCI`)

Comment: I agree. I was just trying to find something with dplyr that would work without calling `do`.

Answer (score 4):

Old question (with plenty of good answers), but this is a great use case for  tidyverse's [broom package](https://broom.tidyverse.org/), which deals with tidying output from test and modeling objects (such as `binom.test`, `lm`, etc).

It's more verbose than other methods, but I think it matches your desire for a more expressive approach.

The process is:

1. Define the groups that you'll run `binom.test` on (in this case, those groups are defined by `x` and `n`) and `nest` them, creating separate data.frames for each (within the full data.frame)
2. `map` the `binom.test` call to the `x` and `n` values from each group
3. `tidy` the `binom.test` output for each group (this is where broom comes in)
4. `unnest` the tidied test output data.frames into the full data.frame

Now you're left with a data.frame where each row contains the `x` and `n` values, combined with all of the output from the corresponding `binom.test`, neatly formatted with separate columns for each bit of output information (point estimate, upper/lower conf, p-value, etc).

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
dd <- data.frame(x=c(3,4),n=c(10,11))
dd %>%
  group_by(x, n) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(test = map(data, ~tidy(binom.test(x, n)))) %>%
  unnest(test)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 11
#> # Groups:   x, n [2]
#>       x     n data  estimate statistic p.value parameter conf.low conf.high
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <lis>    <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     3    10 <tib…    0.3           3   0.344        10   0.0667     0.652
#> 2     4    11 <tib…    0.364         4   0.549        11   0.109      0.692
#> # … with 2 more variables: method <chr>, alternative <chr>
```

From here you can get to your exact desired format with just a bit more manipulation, selecting the desired output variables, and renaming them:

```r
dd %>%
  group_by(x, n) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(test = map(data, ~tidy(binom.test(x, n)))) %>%
  unnest(test) %>%
  rename(lwr = conf.low, upr = conf.high) %>%
  select(x, n, lwr, upr)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#> # Groups:   x, n [2]
#>       x     n    lwr   upr
#>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     3    10 0.0667 0.652
#> 2     4    11 0.109  0.692
```

As mentioned, it's verbose. Much more so than (for example) @joran's beautifully succinct

```r
dd %>% 
    group_by(x,n) %>%
    do(foo(.$x,.$n))
```

However, the benefit of the broom approach is that you won't need to define a function `foo` (or `get_binCI`). It's fully self-contained, and in my opinion far more expressive and flexible.

Comment: Great and up-to-date answer. If compared to the OP's chosen answer, which would be faster (supposing that raw speed is what we are after)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option which relies on mutate and summarise automatically unpacking named tibble results [ref](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/commit/ac6173610e08d95dcb9a3c6c9c5cbef7160a0ef8).

```
dd <- data.frame(x=c(3,4),n=c(10,11))

get_binCI <- function(x,n) {
  s1 <- binom.test(x,n)$conf.int
  names(s1) <- c("lwr", "upr")
  as_tibble(as.list(s1))
}

dd %>% 
  group_by(x,n) %>%
  summarise(get_binCI(x, n))

# A tibble: 2 × 4
# Groups:   x [2]
      x     n    lwr   upr
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1     3    10 0.0667 0.652
2     4    11 0.109  0.692
```

The `as_tibble(as.list())` part can be moved inside `summarise` when using functions like quantile:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(as_tibble(as.list(quantile(mpg))))
```