# Running binom.test over data frame creates error

Tags: r

I am trying to run excact binom.tests over a data frame with multiple rows with the following function and call, as previously presented by [@Joran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29614849/dplyrmutate-to-add-multiple-values):

```
get_binCI <- function(x, n) {
  bi <- binom.test(x,n)$conf.int*100
  data_frame(lwr = bi[1],
             upr = bi[2])
  }

library(dplyr)
df %>%
group_by(col1,col2) %>%
do(get_binCI(.$col1, .$col2)
```

It works on the following data frame:

```
col1 <- c(11,2,7,6,5,2,3,4,1,1,5,8,7,6)
col2 <- c(303,303,303,303,303,471,471,471,471,200,200,200,200,200)
df <- data.frame(col1,col2, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

However, when I try to use it on my own data frame (with multiple other columns and significantly longer than the one above, but otherwise similar), I get the following error:

```
Error in binom.test(x,n) : incorrect length of 'x'
```

So i looked at the source code for the binom.test (below), and found where the error comes from, but I cannot seem to solve the issue...

```
  DNAME <- deparse(substitute(x))
  xr <- round(x)
  if (any(is.na(x) | (x < 0)) || max(abs(x - xr)) > 1e-07) 
    stop("'x' must be nonnegative and integer")
  x <- xr
  if (length(x) == 2L) {
    n <- sum(x)
    x <- x[1L]
  }
  else if (length(x) == 1L) {
    nr <- round(n)
    if ((length(n) > 1L) || is.na(n) || (n < 1) || abs(n - 
      nr) > 1e-07 || (x > nr)) 
      stop("'n' must be a positive integer >= 'x'")
    DNAME <- paste(DNAME, "and", deparse(substitute(n)))
    n <- nr
  }
  else stop("incorrect length of 'x'")
```

As the only difference between the two data frames is the length and the additional columns, I have no clue as to why this error is produced.

Comment: try using `rowwise()` instead of `group_by()`

Comment: @shuckle That worked! However, now I lost all the other columns in the data frame and was only left with the "lwr" and "upr" column... How do I retain the rest of the columns?

Comment: you have a couple of options there. You could join (`bind_cols()`) your results back onto the original dataframe, or you could edit your `get_binCI` function to also return the other columns of the dataframe. You might also be interested in using the `broom` package. https://github.com/tidyverse/broom