# using strsplit and subset in dplyr and mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, strsplit

I have a data table with one string column. I'd like to create another column that is a subset of this column using strsplit.

```
dat <- data.table(labels=c('a_1','b_2','c_3','d_4'))
```

The output I want is

```
label  sub_label
a_1    a
b_2    b
c_3    c
d_4    d
```

I've tried the followings but neither seems to work.

```
dat %>%
    mutate(
        sub_labels=strsplit(as.character(labels), "_")[[1]][1]
    ) 
# gives a column whose values are all "a"
```

this one, which seems logical to me,

```
dat %>%
    mutate(
        sub_labels=sapply(strsplit(as.character(labels), "_"), function(x) x[[1]][1])
    )
```

gives an error

> Error: Don't know how to handle type pairlist

I saw another post where paste-collapse on the output from strsplit worked so I don't understand why subsetting in an anonymous function is giving issues. Thanks for any elucidation on this.

Comment: It's simpler to use regex or `substr`, as they return strings instead of a list: `dat %>% mutate(sub_label = sub('_.*', '', labels))` Another option is `tidyr::separate` with `extra = 'drop'` and `remove = FALSE`: `dat %>% separate(labels, 'sub_label', extra = 'drop', remove = FALSE)`

Comment: weird, I just run your last code `dat %>% mutate(sub_labels=sapply(strsplit(as.character(labels), "_"), function(x) x[[1]][1]))` and it worked fine, did not get an error

Comment: If you have a `data.table` just do `dat[, c("first","second") := tstrsplit(labels,"_")]`

Comment: Thanks @thelatemail. Inexplicably, the output doesn't get printed first time around even when assigned to an object (I assigned it to, say, x and i have to print x twice to see the table), but it works great and is succinct.

Answer (score 47):

[`tidyr::separate`](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html) can help here:

```
> dat %>% separate(labels, c("first", "second") )
   first second
1:     a      1
2:     b      2
3:     c      3
4:     d      4
```

Comment: Though this doesn't retain the original column, which I think is where the problem lies.

Comment: @thelatemail I think you can specify `remove = FALSE` in order to handle that.

Comment: Awesome! I had no idea this function existed. I was trying to solve a similar problem to OP and this is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Another method uses `purrr`'s `map_chr`, which I've found useful for applications where I didn't want to bother with separating and uniting (e.g. using the results in a `sprintf` with other strings):

```
tibble(labels=c('a_1','b_2','c_3','d_4')) %>% 
  mutate(sub_label = stringr::str_split(labels, "_") %>% map_chr(., 1))
```

This method can be substantially faster than `separate` in my experience, especially when you have longer datasets. `separate` barely beats map when I use 100 strings, but falls behind in most cases when I use 1000 (not sure what's up with that max).

```
    > microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
+   d.filtered_reads %>% head(1000) %>% 
+     mutate(name = stringr::str_split(Header, " ") %>% map_chr(., 1)) %>% 
+     select(-Header),
+   d.filtered_reads %>% head(1000) %>% 
+     separate(Header, into = c("name","index"), sep = " ") %>% 
+     select(-"index")
+ )
Unit: milliseconds
                                                                                                                          expr
 d.filtered_reads %>% head(1000) %>% mutate(name = stringr::str_split(Header,      " ") %>% map_chr(., 1)) %>% select(-Header)
          d.filtered_reads %>% head(1000) %>% separate(Header, into = c("name",      "index"), sep = " ") %>% select(-"index")
      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
 5.333891 5.817589 6.292954 5.935706 6.059031 41.530089   100
 7.517316 8.031325 8.399471 8.500359 8.647468  9.855612   100
```

Comment: It is worth to mention that `strsplit` is replaced by `str_split` from `stringr` (https://github.com/tidyverse/stringr). Also, this code works as well an alternative: `dat %>% mutate(sub_label = sapply(str_split(labels, "_"), function(x) x[1]))`

Comment: Thank you! I've added `stringr::` to clarify that. I usually just show that I'm loading tidyverse but I forgot to do that here so it's an important clarification.

Answer (score 10):

I didn't come up with this, I just stumbled on [this github issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/stringr/issues/265) while looking for a solution, and think it is simpler than many of the answers here, particularly avoiding an extra `map_chr()` or `tmp_chunks`.

```
# I used data.frame since I don't have data table installed
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
dat <- data.frame(labels=c('a_1','b_2','c_3','d_4'))
dat %>% mutate(sub_label = str_split(labels, "_", simplify = T)[, 1])
  labels sub_label
1    a_1         a
2    b_2         b
3    c_3         c
4    d_4         d
```

Comment: The map_chr comes in use moreso in the example I mentioned where you're using it with some other function that ends up needing purrr's mapping functionality to get all the vectors to play nicely. :) No doubt this is the simplest solution and is probably the fastest if the goal is simply to extract the character.

Answer (score 5):

In case we want to extract several columns at once (without running the split again, of course) we can combine [GenesRus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9023668/genesrus)'s [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57915361/435004) with a temporary column that we drop with negative `select()` further down the pipeline:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(stringr)

tibble(labels=c('a_1','b_2','c_3','d_4')) %>% 
  mutate(tmp_chunks = stringr::str_split(labels, stringr::fixed("_"),  n = 2)) %>%
  mutate(sub_label = map_chr(tmp_chunks, 1),
         sub_value = map_chr(tmp_chunks, 2)) %>%
  select(-tmp_chunks)
```

As of 2020, performance is [much better than `separate()`](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/72).

For completeness, it is worth mentioning that

- `map_chr` can take a `.default` parameter (in case the separator is missing in some lines),
- one can also get rid of `labels` with negative `select()`, if desired

Comment: Where does fixed() come from? I can't find that function.

Comment: Good catch @GenesRus. [It's from stringr](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/0.6.2/topics/fixed). Updating code excerpt.